# ATI Radeon HD 5750 no DP port?

Tags: amd-radeon, acer-aspire, displayport

I just bought an acer aspire m5400. It states it comes with an AMD Rradeon HR 5750, but when I look at the back it only has three outputs: DVI, VGA and HDMI.

I am trying to connect a third monitor and I read I need a DP port.
I dont have a DP port and everywhere I read it states 5750 has a DP port.
When i check in device manager it shows I am running an AMD HD 5700 series.

Is there another way to check and see what i am actually running without cracking the case open? Did i get scammed and they did not give me a 5750?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, give [**GPU-Z**](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) a spin. It will tell you the exact model card you have.

And are you sure the port is not a DisplayPort? They are very similar to HDMI:

[image]

Comment: It's possible they're using a weird proprietary card that's missing the DP output, as well.  The ports aren't OFFICIALLY standardized to the chip - there are plenty of examples of otherwise identical cards with different outputs on the market.

Comment: nope it is an hdmi. it says hdmi on it and \i have all three monitors connected. one with an hdmi. the computer recognizes all three displays but wont display three

Comment: @Dave Shinrai's comment would make more sense in this case. You can get an HDMI to displayport adapter too if that suits your needs :)

Comment: but i dont have a displayport

Comment: if i just buy an additional ati 5450 would I be able to run 2 video cards and use three monitors that way? 2 on the 5750 hdmi and vga and on the 5450 a dvi?